# Unable to Publish any content from one publication

Tags: 2011, publishing

We have a publication with below blueprint

[image: BluePrint]

When we publish content from `Child1` the items are not getting deployed in file system. But publishing of content from `Child2` is working fine with no issues.

When checked Tridion logs we see below error associated to `Child1`.

```
> Unable to index item: tcm:116-31-4. <html> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
> <title>Error 403 User not in required role</title> </head>
> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2> <p>Problem accessing /tridion/update.
> Reason: <pre>    User not in required role</pre></p><hr
> /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

When publishing item from `Child1` Tridion shows publishing success. Upon expanding publishing transaction it shows `No Details available` and in Processed items shows no item. We tried different publication targets from the publication and nothing is getting published.

The issue is reported only two days early. Prior to that items were getting published with no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Structure Group` was not marked as publishable in Tridion. I have enabled it and items started publishing.

Comment: if your issue resolved you can mark your answer as resovled

Comment: I have marked it as resolved